# Open file explorer and select input file in C, Win32

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, mingw

By using the Win32 API in C, I am trying to open a file explorer and make the user select an file, for which the absolute path will be put into some other function.

I have looked at Microsoft's resources [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog)-[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance)], in order to try to utilize `CoCreateInstance`. However, they specify that five inputs should be given, while every other example, both in [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog)] and in [[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance)], only gives four inputs. Compiling with only four inputs gives me an error in MinGW's GCC.

How can I create retrieve the absolute path from a file that the user specifies through the file explorer?

Moreover, is it possible to apply a filter to the file explorer such that only specified files can be seen? I can only see that this is possible in C#, and not C [[3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)].

Comment: this question really is "what arguments do i pass to CoCreateInstance sice MSFT docs contradict themselves"

Comment: the macro `IID_PPV_ARGS` generates the last 2 arguments of the call

Comment: Thanks. Looking at `combaseapi.h`, the problem seems to be that `IID_PPV_ARGS` is only defined for C++ and not C.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379120/iid-ppv-args-and-dereferencing-null has the definition

Comment: `IID_PPV_ARGS` is provided for convenience and safety only. It isn't mandatory. If the macro isn't available, you can pass the interface ID and address of your out-pointer variable just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create retrieve the absolute path from a file that the user specifies through the file explorer?

When calling `CoCreateInstance()`, you have to give it 5 parameters.  The [`IID_PPV_ARGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) seen in many examples is just a preprocessor macro provided for convenience to generate the last 2 parameters in a type-safe manner, but it is not a requirement.  You can supply the last 2 parameters manually, as long as you are careful with them.  For example:

```
IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
```

Is really just the same as this:

```
IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IFileDialog), (void**)&pfd);
```

Aka:

```
IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFileDialog, (void**)&pfd);
```

> Moreover, is it possible to apply a filter to the file explorer such that only specified files can be seen?

Yes. Use the [`IFileDialog::SetFileTypes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfiletypes) and [`IFileDialog::SetFileTypeIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfiletypeindex) methods.